# How to send a GET request with SetTimeout and get data if it is not ready yet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On Submit click I send a POST request with some data to the server and in response I get an object with **id** and **timeout**. Then I need set timeout and when time comes send a GET request for the data. The problem is that data is not ready yet and I get undefined and my React app crashes.

I was told that timeout should be from the first request only (I mean I can't mannualy increase it or do something like this: `timeout * 2`, I need to use timeout from the first request only). How can I do that? I think it can be done somehow with While loop ...but I'm not smart enough to write this code. Please help

```
const [someData, setSomeData] = useState({}) // here comes undefined and app crashes because this object renders in DOM

const getData = async (id) => {
  const response = await fetch(`$BASE_URL/${id}`)
  setSomeData(response)
}

const onSubmit = async (data) => {
  const { id, timeout } = await fetch(url, data)
  
  setTimeOut(() => {
    getData(id) // data is not ready and I get undefined
  }, timeout) // its around 1000ms and I can't change it mannually
  
}
```

If I do this then everything works fine

```
const getData = async (id) => {
  const response = await fetch(`$BASE_URL/${id}`)
  setSomeData(response)
}

const onSubmit = async (data) => {
  const { id, timeout } = await fetch(url, data)
  
  setTimeOut(() => {
    getData(id) 
  }, 6000) // if I manually specify timeout to 6000
  
}
```

Comment: are you getting id and timeout undefined??

Comment: No. I get undefined from the getData function. Because I need to wait longer than the timeout (can't change it mannualy).

Comment: Where exactly do you get your `undefined` ? In `setSomeData(response)`, the `response === undefined` ?

Comment: Take notice that your `getData` is not returning anything (so it is returning undefined). But the `response` is being set in your `someData` object.

Comment: Added additional info to post

Answer (score -1):

fetch will return a promises, you could use then to getData.

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    fetch(url, data)
      .then(res => return res.json())
      .then(res => getData(res.id))
}
```